# AppleScript to click OK and save file from Firefox link

Tags: applescript

So I have a page with about 60 of links on it, with random URL's, each one needs to be clicked and downloaded individually.

I'm working on the fundamental script to tab over to the next link, hit enter, and then 'ok' to download to desktop.

I'm new, but I cannot seem to get the 'floating' window which pops up, to let me keystroke 'return' or click on 'OK'. I'm looking to save the file to desktop, but I can't seem to reference the window by title in the app, or guess the index number or window ID.

Any help is much appreciated..

I've also seen the dictionary, in script editor, and many of the properties of 'window' for Firefox, throw syntax and other errors.

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell window "$thewindowtitle"
    keystroke tab
    delay 1.0
    keystroke return
end tell
tell application "Firefox"
    tell window visible
    click button "OK"
    end tell
end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Thanks!

Comment: Delay is a large part of the problem, from what I can see so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't seem to support running JavaScripts, but in Safari you might use a script like this to get the URLs of all links:

```
set l to {}
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
    set n to do JavaScript "document.links.length"
    repeat with i from 0 to (n - 1)
        set end of l to (do JavaScript "document.links[" & i & "].href")
    end repeat
end tell
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to l as text
```

And then open them in the default browser:

```
IFS=$'\n' for u in $(pbpaste); do open "$u"; done
```

Or use curl:

```
cd ~/Desktop/; IFS=$'\n'; for u in $(pbpaste); do; curl "$u" -O; done
```

Comment: Are we sure Firefox doesn't support running JavaScripts? Any official docs? Actually a way to execute JS via AS on Firefox would be better.

Comment: I just meant that there was no command for running JavaScripts in its AppleScript dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

See this from another end. In preferences > Firefox Preferences > General > Applications I changed from ask, to save where it says choose the way Firefox handles the files you download. It just saves them all. In my case I created a workflow in Automator to download images from url's. It was quite useful for me.